# How to deploy a symfony app with a database to heroku?

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

How to deploy a symfony app with a database to heroku? The database is created using doctrine and manual queries.

Comment: You can"t ask here for a full guide of how do something. You must have a real programming question that is precise and solvable.
For your database in heroku, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191259/how-to-deploy-local-mysql-database-to-heroku

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole guide to this located at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony already.

Comment: The articles I found was not helpful. I have an already finished symfony app which has a mysql database. None of the articles clearly explain how to add the mysql db. One option was using cleardb. But I was stuck halfway. Thank you.