# Rake assuming wrong database engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I have adapter set to "mysql2" in my database.yml, yet when I try to deploy to Heroku, I get an error telling me, that I don't have Postgres installed... What the heck?

```
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku works ONLY WITH POSTGRESQL

you should add postgresql to envirement what you use on Heroku

**UPDATED**

but Heroku has huck for MySQL:

[TAKE A LOOK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15191367/3884750)

Comment: you can use MySQL for `production`, and PostgeSQL for heroku environment