# How to deploy Go server on Heroku with a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, heroku, go, web-deployment

I am a complete beginner at hosting applications right now but am trying to get a hold of it.
- I have the MySQL database running locally on my PC. How to exactly should I host it somewhere online.
- When I tried to deploy my Go server on Heroku, I got the following error and couldn't find a solution for it anywhere online.

`-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/go.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed`

Any help in this regard would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191259/how-to-deploy-local-mysql-database-to-heroku

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem you need to use some of vendoring tools - e.g. Godep, dep etc.
Heroku can't deploy golang app without 'vendor' folder

Answer (score 0):

just run this command:

```
go mod init [app-name]
```

this will create a go mod file and a go sum for you
then run:

```
go get
```

to install those packages you called in your go app.
developers usually use go mod init github.com/name/repo
but go mod init [app-name]
will do the job!