# Heroku Rails mySql (mysql2 gem) migrations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, mysql2

Been able to make migrations (add columns etc) on my local machine with mysql.

But when trying to push these migrations to Heroku, they continue to fail.

The first table in my migration file gets tagged with:

```
 Mysql2::Error: Table 'xxxxx' already exists
```

locally all my migrations showing as:

```
 up     20171127214206  Add tags to business
```

but when running heroku run rake db:migrate:status

```
 down    20171127214206  Add tags to business
```

i don't mind losing all the data at this point as i'm working in a development version on Heroku and will merge later with production

been working on this issue for over a day, so any and all advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191259/how-to-deploy-local-mysql-database-to-heroku) and many other sources, it appears you're better to use postgresql adapter with heroku. If you want to do that, you need to edit your database.yml similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/goncalvesjoao/4388cc1455f78785829eb6db8e6ef74f)

Comment: i ended up resetting the database and losing all the data (thankfully it was the test/dev version), but i 100% agree with you, just i'm not the owner of the project and they created it with mySql