# Connecting to MySQL with Node Js on a Live Server

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a project that I am working on that is written in node js, and I am using mysql for database. I deployed my app on Heroku but Heroku doesn't seem to support mysql databases. Is there a website like mlab.com where I can connect to mysql while having my app hosted on Heroku? Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Heroku MySQL to Postgresql](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql)(retrieved 2018), there are a number of [MySQL/[MariaDB]](https://elements.heroku.com/search/addons?q=mysql) addon services.

Related is the previous answer: [How to deploy local MySQL database to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191259/how-to-deploy-local-mysql-database-to-heroku#15191367)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to connect your node js to your MySQL Database on a live server

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
 
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',     // your root username
  database : 'yourdatabase'   // the name of your db
});
```