# How to upload local mysql database to heroku app?

Tags: python, mysql, heroku

I have a web application written in Python-Flask with database created using MySQL. I have deployed my app using Heroku but it's only the frontend and backend part. I also need to upload database so that the app can interact with the database. I have searched many videos on YouTube but nothing came as useful. Most of them are using Postgre SQL both in local and heroku app but I've an MySQL database with me. I need help how can I connect my app to my database.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has native support for postgessql not mysql, so you might want to change to that or use the [Clear DB addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb) as explained in the docs.

From heroku

> "Heroku provides three managed data services to all customers:
>
> Heroku Postgres, Heroku Redis, Apache Kafka on Heroku"

Also have a look at this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15191367/1831811) that targets the same issue.